# gh release create TAG aws codecommit equivalent

Tags: git, version-control, aws-cli, aws-codecommit, github-cli

Anyone know of a `gh release create TAG` aws codecommit equivalent?

I'm looking for a way on AWS to track the exact state of the repo per a release number I'd keep in line with app build numbers, as in when releasing the app on Store, hit `release create`. Idea being to track crashes on Crashlytics to anything newly introduced.

For e.g. "This crash stared .X releases ago, that was the first time Y npm was installed to production"...

Don't think I've missed anything obvious? Git Tags are per commit, right? So wouldn't show Z dev added the npm 5 commits ago, but it's only just made it into the app?

How are you guys visualising anything newly introduced per build on AWS?

Many thanks